# Property 'type' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Props'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

** In react-router v6 I am passing element so in typescript its asking for props how i can solve that**

````
     <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
     <Route path="fellows" element={<AllFellow />} />
     <Route path="schools" element={<AllSchool />} />
     <Route path="pgestudents" element={<PgeStudents />} />
     <Route path="ecestudents" element={<EceStudents />} />
     <Route path="fellow/:fellowid" element={<IndividualFellow />} />
</Routes>```

**Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Props':**
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined props correctly in the component file, you should adjust the element declaration by passing the name of the parameter e.g:

```
<Dashboard dashboard_id={''} />
```

instead of just

```
 <Dashboard/>
```

Visual studio code provides this option as a quick fix to the error